# I am no longer getting an output file on my python code in pycharm

Tags: python, output, driver, python-3.7, gdal

No longer getting output file on pycharm.

I previously got an output file, but it would not update with changes in "data_to_write". I moved the output file to another location, but did not change the output directory path for the output file I need to generate. Pycharm is no longer creating an output file.

```
def main():
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('JPEG')
driver.Register()

sdsu_in = './data/SDSU_3Color.jpg'
# open and read only jpeg file
data = gdal.Open(sdsu_in, gdalconst.GA_ReadOnly)

if data is None:
    print("Error: Could not read '{}'".format(sdsu_in))
    sys.exit()

rows = data.RasterYSize
cols = data.RasterXSize
r_bands = data.RasterCount
proj = data.GetProjectionRef()
m_data = data.GetMetadata()
geotrans = data.GetGeoTransform()
x_origin = geotrans[0]
y_origin = geotrans[3]
pixel_width = geotrans[1]
pixel_height = geotrans[5]

print("The # of rows: {}, The # of columns: {}, raster bands: {}, "
      "metadata: {}".format(rows, cols, r_bands, proj, m_data))

data_to_write = f'The number of rows: {rows}\n The number of columns 
{cols}\n The number of raster bands: {r_bands}\n The projection: {proj}\n 
The metadata: {m_data}\n The Geotransform information: {geotrans}\n X 
Origin: {x_origin}\n Y Origin: {y_origin}\n Pixel Width: {pixel_width}\n 
Pixel Height: {pixel_height}'

# creating new output with specified information
sdsu_out = './output/output_w1.txt'
with open(sdsu_out, 'w') as f:
    f.write(data_to_write)
    f.flush()
    f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Code is much longer than this, but this is a simple .txt file I need to create. I got an output last night, but it would not update with changed code, so I added a "1" to end to create (hopefully) a new file in the output directory. I did not alter the output directory relative path. Rest of code is very long, so I did not upload it. No red errors on debugging, only 6 weak warning.

Thank you for your help.
** code is indented perfectly on pycharm, but not going to add 4 spaces to each line..

Comment: First thing I noticed was the use of `.flush()` and `.close()`. Those are not needed when using `with`. I don’t imagine that’s what’s causing the problem, but it can only be beneficial to fix it.

Comment: I have deleted both flush and close from my code, still no output. Maybe I will try updating conda and my virtual python environment?

Comment: It can't really hurt to try, although I would be shocked if that solved anything. As an aside, you wrote that the code is indented perfectly on PyCharm but not here. That may be because you're using the "4 spaces" method to create a code block. Take a look at the part about "code fences" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). I use "\`\`\`" (3 backticks) which I find so much easier than the alternatives.

Comment: Yes, updating did not solve anything. Pycharm allows the "tab" button to create 4 spaces and even shows alignment lines to ensure all parts of the code are uniformally indented. Thank you so much for your suggestions. I remain very frustrated and confused.

Comment: Is there any other way for you to share the code, so that I can give the formatting a try?

Comment: The file path ('./output/output_w1.txt') is correct, right?

Comment: yes. the exact relative file path provide a txt file last night. I do not believe stackoverflow will allow me to share the entire code as it is very long

Comment: How long are we talking here? Does all of it have an effect on the file output part, or can it be narrowed down?

Comment: just tried the absolute path as well. no results

Comment: code is 200 lines and further reads large raster data under 'HFA' driver

Comment: Have you tried inserting something like a print statement just before the file writing code, to check if that code is actually run?

Comment: yes print statement is included before. Does not print. Do not have any errors debugging however. Very confused. Thanks for your comments and help.
Run finishes with "Process finished with exit code 0"

Comment: Well if it doesn't print then we know the issue is _not_ related to files, right?

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that something changed the present working directory of your Pycharm environment.

Just add following line directly before the `with open(` statement. It will print out the present working directory.
I then suggest you use a file explorer and look and that directory to see whether the file really hasn't been created

```
print("I will create the file ", sdsu_out, "in the directory ", os.path.realpath(os.path.getcwd())
```

and add the line

```
import os
```

at the beginning of the file if `os` hasn't been imported so far.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I tried pasting the code before the with open() statement. 
Nothing prints..Pycharm's answer "Process finished with exit code 0"
I have checked the file directory as well and the output folder is empty, Several other files were supposed to output into the output directory as well, but having luck with none. Thought I'd start with a simple txt file to see if I could resolve the issue. 
Thank you.

Comment: Your indentation isn't 100% correct. Pls fix and post a complete example, that you tried also on your machine.

you could add the  print statement at the beginning (after the `import os`) or at the end of the file without any indentation. This might give you an idea. 
Perhaps your main function isn't executed at all due to some issue.
Or you edit one python file with a given name, but you execute another one in another directory or on another machine. (Both happened already to me and I needed quite some time to figure out)

Comment: Stack Overflow altered my indentations because of my f'string of "data_to_write"
My code is too long to post in comments

Comment: In general you get the highest quality answers if you manage to reduce your complex huge code to a very small functional code snippet that still reproduces the issue.

In fact sometimes just writing that example makes an issue so obvious that you don't even have to ask the question anymore. (This happened to me also quite often)

Comment: I'd still suggest to add the print at the beginning of the file and at the end of the file. then you should see the present working directory in which the files should occur. In most cases it's just that the code executes in another directory as assumed.

if you don't see any console output or if the console output disappears immediateley, then try following line at the beginning and at the end of the file:

`import os, time; print(os.path.realpath(os.getcwd())) ; time.sleep(5)`
and look for the output.

Comment: re-posted code with proper indentation (stackoverflow is very annoying to continually indent 4 spaces each line)
Hope this helps!

Comment: the line
`if __name__ == "__main__":` should not be indented.

Did you try to `print / sleep` lines, that I suggested?

Comment: concerning indentation with SO.
Just copy / paste the entire code (of your simplified example) into the question, select it with the mouse and click on '{}' or press Ctrl-K to mark it as source code.

Comment: I did get a print. I am in the right directory: C:\Users\sarah\PycharmProjects\GEOG582\a08_wozniak, in which "output" is a folder under the directory "a08_wozniak"

Comment: okay. Having "if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()" indented seems to have been a HUGE problem!

Comment: GUYSSSS!! I have an output txt file! Thank you! I love you!!!!

Comment: yes if the `if __name__ == "__main__"` is indented it is part of the main function.

However this line must be at the top level to ensure, that the main function is called.

Comment: yes thank you. I am quite new to python. Such an elementary and emotionally taxing mix-up. THANK YOU for your simple but immensely helpful input!